# Can't access spark UI even if I use the ip address reported in the console

Tags: docker, apache-spark, spark-ui

I cannot access the web UI of my containerized spark cluster even if I copy and paste the following Ip address:

```
Stopped Spark web UI at http://987c8b219d32:4040
```

The cluster that I've built is taken from this tutorial [Spark Cluster Tutorial](https://dev.to/mvillarrealb/creating-a-spark-standalone-cluster-with-docker-and-docker-compose-2021-update-6l4)

Answer (score 0):

The log specifies that the web UI is stopped. You can't access the Web UI after the spark application have stopped as it is explained in the documentation:

> Note that this information is only available for the duration of the
> application by default.

To enable accessing the web UI after the application have stopped you need to:

> set spark.eventLog.enabled to true before starting the application. This
> configures Spark to log Spark events that encode the information
> displayed in the UI to persisted storage.

Please check the documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#web-interfaces).

Also note, that in the tutorial, the default web UI ports are changed to:

```
SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=8080 \
SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT=8080 \
```

and that they are exposed outside the container in the docker-compose file to the ports 9090, 9091 and 9092:

```
  - "9090:8080"
  - "9091:8080"
  - "9092:8080"
```

Which means that you can access the Web UI using: `http://localhost:9090`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But the web UI at localhost:9090 doesn't have the stages,jobs,environment...tabs. I need those tabs for monitoring the workload. Following this discussion [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56397738/sparkui-not-showing-tab-jobs-stages-storage-environment-when-run-in-sta) don't work for me because when I click I get the page not found due to this wrong ip address associated to such link: http://987c8b219d32:4040/ but if I switch it to 9090 as suggested before it return the main page, I would like to know the path to paste in order to access to such infos.

Comment: The stages, jobs ... won't appear unless your jobs is still running or the history server is enabled.